# Export a MYSQL column to a plain txt file with no headings

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, export

So what I'm trying to do is write a script or CRON job (Linux- CentOS) to export the usernames listed in my wordpress database to a simple .txt file with just on username per line. So with the picture, I would like the .txt file to read like this:

- Sir_Fluffulus
- NunjaX007

(Except with all the username in the user_login column.)

See screenshot at:

[image]

I have found how to export the entire table to a CVS file, but that contains about 10+ fields (Columns) that I DO NOT what to show up in this text file. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

If it helps, this is going to be for exporting users that have signed up on our website (Wordpress) to a whitelist.txt file for Minecraft. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a query into the `mysql` tool, and use silent mode.

```
$ mysql -u username dbname -s <<< 'SELECT fieldname FROM tablename'
Sir_Fluffulus
NunjaX007
```

Comment: You will then want to redirect the output to file. Since you are running this as a cron job, and I presume your database is password protected, you will need to take sensible precautions to protect the credentials.

Comment: That command worked great! So who would I get that output to be sent into my .txt file? (Sorry, I'm a newbie to MYSQL)

Comment: @Kohl: Redirect it to a file: `someprog > somefile`